# При запуске через supervisor uwsgi не видит приложение Django

Tags: python, linux, django, развертывание, supervisord

Есть приложение на django, если просто запустить его глобально через терминал командой `uwsgi --ini /path/to/file.ini`  - все ок, приложение открыватеся. Если сделать то же самое через supervisor - я получаю ошибку `Internal server error`.

То есть супервизор запускает команду, если бы это было не так, я бы получил стандартную 502 ошибку, но я вижу ошибку именно на уровне uwsgi.  О чем он и сообщает мне в логе:

```
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
```

Еще одна странность - вчера у меня уже была аналогичная проблема, я не понял причины, но при этом удалось решить ее заменой в конфиге uwsgi указания модуля на указание непосредственного пути к файлу wsgi. На какое-то время все заработало, а потом опять отвалилось:

```
#Было 
module          = main_app.wsgi

#Стало
wsgi-file = /path/to/project/main_app/wsgi.py
```

Я уже совершенно не знаю как быть, помогите пожалуйста

UPD: конфиг супервизора:

```
[program:domobot]
user=kkomissarov
command=uwsgi --emperor "/home/kkomissarov/domobot/deployment/domobot_uwsgi.ini"
stdout_logfile=/home/kkomissarov/domobot/log/uwsgi.log
stderr_logfile=/home/kkomissarov/domobot/log/uwsgi_err.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

Лог ошибок uwsgi (пути настоящие, а в примере выше - нет)

```
Wed Oct  2 18:11:25 2019 - [emperor] vassal /home/kkomissarov/domobot.kkomissarov.ru/deployment/domobot_uwsgi.ini is ready to accept requests
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 2996|app: -1|req: -1/1] 188.243.32.103 () {44 vars in 915 bytes} [Wed Oct  2 18:12:31 2019] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
Wed Oct  2 18:12:31 2019 - [emperor] vassal /home/kkomissarov/domobot.kkomissarov.ru/deployment/domobot_uwsgi.ini is now loyal
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 2997|app: -1|req: -1/2] 188.243.32.103 () {44 vars in 915 bytes} [Wed Oct  2 18:12:32 2019] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
Wed Oct  2 18:12:32 2019 - [emperor] vassal /home/kkomissarov/domobot.kkomissarov.ru/deployment/domobot_uwsgi.ini is now loyal
```

Конфиг uwsgi

```
[uwsgi]

# Настройки, связанные с Django
# Корневая папка проекта (полный путь)
chdir           = /home/kkomissarov/domobot.kkomissarov.ru/project

# Django wsgi файл
#module          = main_app.wsgi
wsgi-file = /home/kkomissarov/domobot.kkomissarov.ru/project/main_app/wsgi.py


# полный путь к виртуальному окружению
home            = /home/kkomissarov/domobot.kkomissarov.ru/venv

# общие настройки
# master
master          = true
# максимальное количество процессов
processes       = 10
# полный путь к файлу сокета
socket          = /home/kkomissarov/domobot.kkomissarov.ru/domobot.sock
# права доступа к файлу сокета
chmod-socket    = 666
# очищать окружение от служебных файлов uwsgi по завершению
vacuum          = true

#Рестарт при обновлении файла
touch-reload    = /home/kkomissarov/domobot.kkomissarov.ru/log/reload
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99403/discussion-on-question-by------supervisor-uws).

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, причина была в том, что я брал в настройках приложения ключ из переменной окружения. Переменная окружения была прописана в `/etc/environment`. Но, как выяснилось, для supervisor моя переменная не существовала. Чтобы решить этот вопрос, я просто добавил свой ключ в конфиг супервизора:

```
[program:domobot]
user=kkomissarov
command=uwsgi --emperor "/home/kkomissarov/domobot/deployment/domobot_uwsgi.ini"
stdout_logfile=/home/kkomissarov/domobot/log/uwsgi.log
stderr_logfile=/home/kkomissarov/domobot/log/uwsgi_err.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
environment=MY_SUPERSECRET_KEY="my_supersecret_string"
```